Boostrap/switch component: how do I style the light blue "halo" that shows up when I click on the input?
I tried inspecting for css changes but nothing is showing up in browser tools.
Any ideas? Thanks!
click here for demo: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/checks-radios/#switches
EDIT: if anyone else is reading this, it's the box-shadow property in input:focus or use the focus ring as mentioned below.

This is known as the focus ring. By default, a CSS outline is defined; you can override this with the .focus-ring class and a number of CSS/SASS variables.
